# OKD: Web updater states "Up to date", but newer versions are available

Tags: openshift, upgrade, openshift-origin, okd

We run a OKD (Openshift) Cluster with the version "4.4.0-0.okd-2020-05-23-055148-beta5" since approximately one year. The Web updater states "Up to date" which can't be true as there are much more recent versions of OKD. Does somebody have an idea how we can update to 4.5 or later? Or is this for some reason not possible.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards
Elias

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with the upgrade path. So for your version, there may not  be an upgrade available to any other version.

You can check on which channel you are and then you can find more information in the OKD documentation: [OKD upgrade channels and releases](https://docs.okd.io/latest/updating/updating-cluster-between-minor.html#understanding-upgrade-channels_updating-cluster-between-minor). Different channels have different versions available and not every version allows upgrading to any other version.

You could also try upgrading using the CLI with the following command: `oc adm upgrade --to-latest=true`